# How to get didselect row index no. if you have custom button on cell ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a custom tableview and when i use to click on each row and in didselect i use to get row index value. But in custom row cell  i have added one button on which alert will open with options. But when I use to click on button didselect method did not call.
So please help me out with this . I want row index value when i use click on button.

In this image link you can see the UI. I have added three dot button so i want row index value when i use to click on that button

[image: In this image link you can see the UI. I have added three dot button so i want row index value when i use to click on that button]

This method giving me row value when i use to click on name and image , but when i use to click on button it doe snot give me row value.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let data:DataViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dataviewcontroller") as! DataViewController

    let getdata =  files_dict[indexPath.row]!
  print(indexPath.row)
    data.urlsting = getdata
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(data, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The button is a view. It has a superview which is the tableview cell (there may be several levels). Once you have the tableview cell, you can find its row index.

Comment: Can you please help we with code. I am very new to ios programming . Thanks in advance @gnasher729